# Sum of all the perfect squares

Tags: python

Since I am new to the `python`, someone please help me with this problem

here are the few examples how it should work:

```
input: l([1,4,9])
result=14
```

---

```
input: l(10,11,12,15)
result= 0
```

Comment: This seems like homework. Many such similar questions have been asked before. Please show what you have done first, to solve this problem before asking for code.

Comment: Exact duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45534958/write-code-for-sum-of-perfect-squares-in-a-list-using-python (deleted - need 10k to see.) Or picture: https://puu.sh/x86i2/6876a4f08b.png

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I see a 404 polyglot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question right, you are asking how to write a function to loop through all the values in a list, sum the numbers that are perfect squares, and ignore the others.

Here is my code with comments explaining what is going on.

```py
# We need to use the math module in this program.
import math

# Function declaration
def sumSquares(numbers):

    # Start by defining the sum as 0
    sum = 0

    # Loop through each number in the list
    for num in numbers:

        # Check if number is a square by:
        # 1. Taking the integer square root of that number
        # 2. Squaring it
        # 3. And checking if that is equal to the original number
        if num == int(math.sqrt(num)) ** 2:

            # If it is a perfect square, add it to the total sum.
            sum += num
```

You can call this function like:

```
sumSquares([1, 4, 9, 30])
```

Comment: In my code 'for' loop was returning only the first perfect square number but now i know what was i doing wrong. thank you.

Comment: Hi, if the answer worked for you, please mark it as accepted by pressing the check mark on the left side of the answer, thanks!

Comment: @Sawan Listen. If you attempted something, you should post your attempt so you can be told where you are going wrong.

Comment: actually I am using this site for the very first time so i dont know how you guys prefer things here but i'll keep that in mind.

Comment: @Sawan Thanks. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

According to your question, you can declare a function `is_square(n)` to check a number whether perfect square or not.

Then, you take a number (i.e. `val`) from list `l` using this `for val in l:`. If number (i.e. `val`) is perfect square then it will add to the `sm` otherwise not.

You code will be like following code :

```
l = [1,4,9]

def is_square(n): # function for checking a number whether perfect square or not.
    return n**0.5 == int(n**0.5)

sm = 0
for val in l:
    if is_square(val): # if number is perfect square then it will add to the sm otherwise not.
        sm += val
print(sm)
```

Comment: Why downvote ??

Comment: Propaby because you don't explain your code.

Comment: @Md.RezwanulHaque what downvote???

Comment: I answered your question. But I got downvote for answer . So, I asked why . @Sawan.

Comment: No problem man. Also consider using the 1st comment as a docstring in `is_square` and the 2nd comment as a small explanation above your code. I think it would improve the quality and readability of your post.

Comment: actually i am new to this site so i dont know what you are talking about !!

Comment: @Md.RezwanulHaque i dont even know how to vote here. please explain.

Comment: @Sawan don't worry about it, you don't have enough rep yet.

Comment: You can't upvote any question or answer if your reputation is less than `15`. 
For downvote your minimum reputation need `125`.

Comment: @t.m.adam. Again thanks. :) :D

Comment: Yep, this is much better

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
list = [4,9,55]
sq = []
for i in list:
    if i**0.5 == int(i**0.5):
        sq.append(i)
sum = 0
for i in sq:
    sum = sum + i
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This:

```
import math
a=map(int,input().split())
sum1=0
for i in a:
    b=math.sqrt(i)
    if math.ceil(b)==math.floor(b):
        sum1+=i
print (int(sum1))
```

Comment: Why devote?What problem with my code?